# Is this a correct definition for an injective function

Tags: functions

For a function $F: X\rightarrow Y$

Is:$$(1).\forall x\in X . \exists! y\in Y. (x,y)\in F $$

equivalent to $$(2).\forall a,b\in X. f(a)= f(b) \implies a=b$$

i.e. is the first statement a definition for an injective function

update:

So from the answer it would appear that a function that is injective will satisify (1) however also in (1) are functions where $$a,b \in X. f(a)=f(b)$$ $$a\neq b$$

i.e. multiple elements in X are mapped to a single element in Y

Comment: It is not equivalent!

Comment: @arberavdullahu Have a look at the answer and reconsider

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The first thing you wrote is part of the definition that $F$ is a function.

Recall the definition of a function:

$F: X\rightarrow Y$ is a function

$\iff$

1) $F \subset X \times Y$;

2) $\forall x \in X: \exists!y \in Y: y = F(x)$

Alternatively, we can write 2) as : $\forall x \in X: \exists!y \in Y: (x,y) \in F$, since $F $ is a relation.

Comment: So you can have the case where $f(a) = f(b)$ but $a \neq b$ in the first definition but not the second?

Comment: Yes $f(a) = f(b)$ with $a \neq b$ happens with all non-injective functions, by definition. For example, consider $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: x\mapsto x^2$. Clearly f(-1) = f(1) = 1, hence $f$ is not injective.